# How to figure out root cause of failure of name resolusion while traceroute works

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I have developed a sample app and deployed it, after setting DNS, I try to access `https://dev-intra.test.co.jp/test` (host names have been redacted here). But I didn't reach my app.

I try to figure out root cause of this.

`traceroute` results success.

```
myPC@hikaru:~$ traceroute dev-intra.test.co.jp
traceroute to dev-intra.test.co.jp (192.168.88.11), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  hikaru.mshome.net (172.18.160.1)  0.531 ms  0.507 ms  0.499 ms
 2  * 10.10.10.1 (10.10.10.1)  28.829 ms *
 3  * * *
 4  * 192.168.2.197 (192.168.2.197)  28.617 ms  28.612 ms
 5  * dev-intra.test.co.jp (192.168.88.11)  39.146 ms *
```

So I try to `dig dev-intra.test.co.jp` but it seems that name didn't resolved.

```
; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1.2-Ubuntu <<>> dev-intra.test.co.jp +multiline
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 13425
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;dev-intra.test.co.jp. IN A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
inf9.co.jp.             222 IN SOA ik0103.i-kyushu.or.jp. root.i-kyushu.or.jp. (
                                2022122301 ; serial
                                3600       ; refresh (1 hour)
                                300        ; retry (5 minutes)
                                3600000    ; expire (5 weeks 6 days 16 hours)
                                300        ; minimum (5 minutes)
                                )

;; Query time: 39 msec
;; SERVER: 172.18.160.1#53(172.18.160.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Mon Jan 23 20:10:36 JST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 114
```

Additional info as requested:

```
hikamiya@AT-MPC22151:~$ grep host /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:          files dns
hikamiya@AT-MPC22151:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.18.160.1
hikamiya@AT-MPC22151:~$ resolvectl
sd_bus_open_system: No such file or directory
hikamiya@AT-MPC22151:~$ grep dev-intra /etc/hosts
192.168.88.11   dev-intra.test.co.jp
hikamiya@AT-MPC22151:~$
```

Additional information:

```
hikamiya@AT-MPC22151:~$ cat /var/run/nscd/socket
cat: /var/run/nscd/socket: No such file or directory
hikamiya@AT-MPC22151:~$ cat /run/nscd/socket
cat: /run/nscd/socket: No such file or directory
hikamiya@AT-MPC22151:~$ getent hosts dev-intra.test.co.jp
192.168.88.11   dev-intra.test.co.jp
```

What may be the cause of the discrepancies between them? Am I missing a big point?

If anyone has any opinion, will you please let me know?
Thanks

Comment: What's the output of `grep host /etc/nsswitch.conf`, `cat /etc/resolv.conf`, `resolvectl`, `grep dev-intra /etc/hosts`?

Comment: Thank you for comment,I edited my questoin and add suggested info. Thanks !

Comment: Is there a name service cache daemon running (a `/var/run/nscd/socket` or `/run/nscd/socket` socket present)? What's the OS (Debian, RedHat... not just "Linux" which is just the kernel and not fully relevant here)?

Comment: I take it `getent hosts dev-intra.test.co.jp` also succeeds?

Comment: btw I receive `SSL_ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR_ALERT`, Do you mean it to be https? Have you then certificates?

Comment: I added additional info. actually I edited domain name, I think as it is a little sensitive. As I am novice. sorry for inconvenience . and I edited my post. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`traceroute` uses the system's name service to resolve host names to network addresses.

That's configured via `/etc/nsswitch.conf` (name service switch) which for each database (`passwd`, `group`, `hosts`...) specifies which name service module to use and in what order.

For you, for `hosts`, it says to use the `files` module first, and then DNS. `libnss_files.so` queries plain text files in `/etc`. For the `hosts` database, that's `/etc/hosts`.

Here, it finds you hostname in there, so DNS servers don't even need to be queried.

`dig` itself is only a DNS client. By default, it queries the first server mentioned in `/etc/resolv.conf` (also the configuration for `libnss_dns.so`), and the DNS server doesn't have a record for that host name.